# FirebaseError: Firebase: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists with different options or config (app/duplicate-app)

Tags: typescript, firebase, next.js

[image]

This is My full code

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "APIKEY",
  authDomain: "AUTHDOMAIN",
  projectId: "PROJID",
  storageBucket: "BUCKET",
  messagingSenderId: "SOMEID",
  appId: "APPID",
  measurementId: "IDDDDD"
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = getAuth(app);
```

So I don't know What is happening with my code and How can I fix it? All my code is seem alright and not having any error D:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes, when you import the firebase.js file in multiple other files, it may try to create two instances of the app. To prevent this, make use of the following code:

```
const app = !getApps().length ? initializeApp(firebaseConfig) : getApp();
```

Just be sure to import getApps() and getApp().